# Paperclip reprocess new style with new format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image-processing, imagemagick, paperclip

Below is a hash of my paperclip thumb style types.  Ive added new image types in the past and backfilled only the specific versions by using the **Image.find(some_id).image.reprocess! :sailthru_bid_now**

This command and approach  has always worked.

Recently I added a new image type :sailthru_bid_now, that uses format png.  Works perfectly creating new images, but when I try to run the command  to backfill the type, it runs without error, and doesn't create the new type. WEIRD!  If i remove the custom format it works.

So here I am, begging for any help! Thanks a million in advance.

**ManualCropper.rb**

```
THUMB_STYLES = {
  home_page_thumb: "216x223#",
  thumb: "85x60#",
  large_list: "150x200>",
  detail: '420x2000>',
  full_screen: '1024x1004>',
  featured: '159x116#',
  iframethumb: '266x207#',
  sailthru: '274x282#',
  :sailthru_bid_now => {
     :geometry       => '274x282#',
     :watermark_path => "public/images/bid_now_watermark.jpg",
     :format => 'png'
  },
  #IOS IMAGES SIZES
  ios_small_thumb: '75x75#',
  ios_large_thumb: '158x158#'
}
```

**Image.rb:**

```
has_attached_file(:image, :styles => Paperclip::ManualCropper::THUMB_STYLES,
                    :processors => [:manual_cropper,:watermark],
                    :storage => :s3,
                    :s3_credentials => Rails.application.config.s3_yaml_path,
                    :path => "images/:id/:style.:extension")

  validates :image, :presence => true
  validate :file_dimensions, :unless => "errors.any?"
```

Comment: Are you sure the custom processor works? I mean, if it's not running, perhaps its failing silently? Have you had it working without backfill?

Comment: Seems to work fine, it's generating the new image after my first processor runs (cropping).